# How to add multiple lines in a file after a pattern which is also multi line?

Tags: shell, sed

I have a file where I need to add set of lines after some pattern. The problem is I am not able to handle the pattern which has multiple lines.

**Pattern**

```
<stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
</TestPlan>
<hashTree>
```

**Lines to be added after this pattern**

```
<org.apache.jmeter.config.RestServerNodeElement guiclass="TestBeanGUI"
  testclass="org.apache.jmeter.config.RestServerNodeElement"
  testname="ATC_Test_Lab" enabled="true">
<stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"> </stringProp>
<stringProp name="authbasic">${Basic}</stringProp>
<stringProp name="authpassword">ENC(dsxxxxxxxxxxxWiu+FCzl5+A==)</stringProp>
<stringProp name="authuser">${User}</stringProp>
<stringProp name="extratag"></stringProp>
```

I tried `sed` command with option `-r` as below but it didn’t worked

```
sed -i.bak '/^<stringProp
name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>/{N;/\n</TestPlan>/{N;/\n<hashTree>/r
Config.jmx' $file
```

file `Config.jmx` has the set of lines which needs to be added after this pattern.

Error:-

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 116: unterminated `s' command
```

Comment: did you see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23234681/adding-xml-element-in-xml-file-using-sed-command-in-shell-script

Comment: try a delimiter other than `/` for example: `sed 's#search#replace#'`

Answer (score 0):

Let's avoid boring approaches like reading the whole line as a string in some scripting language and doing a regex substitution with embedded newlines.

State machine approach in Awk. Each line is printed. If the three required lines appear consecutively, the `state` variable increments to 2 and the required block is printed. For any other input, `state` lapses to zero.

```
1
1 { print state }
state == 0 && /^<stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"><\/stringProp>$/ {
  state++; next
}
state == 1 && /^<\/TestPlan>$/ {
  state++; next
}
state == 2 && /^<hashTree>$/ {
  print \
  "<org.apache.jmeter.config.RestServerNodeElement guiclass=\"TestBeanGUI\"\n" \
  "testclass=\"org.apache.jmeter.config.RestServerNodeElement\"\n" \
  "testname=\"ATC_Test_Lab\" enabled=\"true\">\n" \
  "<stringProp name=\"TestPlan.comments\"> </stringProp>\n" \
  "<stringProp name=\"authbasic\">${Basic}</stringProp>\n" \
  "<stringProp name=\"authpassword\">ENC(dsxxxxxxxxxxxWiu+FCzl5+A==)</stringProp>\n" \
  "<stringProp name=\"authuser\">${User}</stringProp>\n" \
  "<stringProp name=\"extratag\"></stringProp>\n"
}
1 {
  state = 0;
}
```

Multi-line match and output in [TXR](http://nongnu.org/txr). The rare approach here is to use the `data` directive to capture two points in the input stream (which is a lazy list of strings) and then the Lisp function `ldiff` to get the range of lines between those two points (i.e. the block that was matched) so that it can be output with `tprint`:

```
@(repeat)
@  (cases)
@    (data start)
<stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
</TestPlan>
<hashTree>
@    (data end)
@    (do (tprint (ldiff start end)))
@    (output)
<org.apache.jmeter.config.RestServerNodeElement guiclass="TestBeanGUI"
  testclass="org.apache.jmeter.config.RestServerNodeElement"
  testname="ATC_Test_Lab" enabled="true">
<stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"> </stringProp>
<stringProp name="authbasic">${Basic}</stringProp>
<stringProp name="authpassword">ENC(dsxxxxxxxxxxxWiu+FCzl5+A==)</stringProp>
<stringProp name="authuser">${User}</stringProp>
<stringProp name="extratag"></stringProp>
@    (end)
@  (or)
@line
@    (do (put-line line))
@  (end)
@(end)
```

In this approach we could add some variables into the block of code being matched and then refer to them in the `@(output)`. Kind of how like a `s/regexp/replace/` can refer to captured pieces via `\1`, `\2`, `&` and so on. Suppose that instead of the static word `TestPlan`, a piece of text had to be extracted, and the duplicated in all the places where `TestPlan` appears now:

```
@(repeat)
@  (cases)
@    (data start)
<stringProp name="@TYPE.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
</@TYPE>
<hashTree>
@    (data end)
@    (do (tprint (ldiff start end)))
@    (output)
<org.apache.jmeter.config.RestServerNodeElement guiclass="TestBeanGUI"
  testclass="org.apache.jmeter.config.RestServerNodeElement"
  testname="ATC_Test_Lab" enabled="true">
<stringProp name="@TYPE.comments"> </stringProp>
<stringProp name="authbasic">${Basic}</stringProp>
<stringProp name="authpassword">ENC(dsxxxxxxxxxxxWiu+FCzl5+A==)</stringProp>
<stringProp name="authuser">${User}</stringProp>
<stringProp name="extratag"></stringProp>
@    (end)
@  (or)
@line
@    (do (put-line line))
@  (end)
@(end)
```

Let's try this version:

```
$ txr add.txr -
foo
foo
bar 
bar
blah
blah
<stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
</TestPlan>
<hashTree>
<stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
</TestPlan>
<hashTree>
<org.apache.jmeter.config.RestServerNodeElement guiclass="TestBeanGUI"
  testclass="org.apache.jmeter.config.RestServerNodeElement"
  testname="ATC_Test_Lab" enabled="true">
<stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"> </stringProp>
<stringProp name="authbasic">${Basic}</stringProp>
<stringProp name="authpassword">ENC(dsxxxxxxxxxxxWiu+FCzl5+A==)</stringProp>
<stringProp name="authuser">${User}</stringProp>
<stringProp name="extratag"></stringProp>


blah
blah
blah
blah
<stringProp name="EvilPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>  
</EvilPlan>
<hashTree>
<stringProp name="EvilPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
</EvilPlan>
<hashTree>
<org.apache.jmeter.config.RestServerNodeElement guiclass="TestBeanGUI"
  testclass="org.apache.jmeter.config.RestServerNodeElement"
  testname="ATC_Test_Lab" enabled="true">
<stringProp name="EvilPlan.comments"> </stringProp>
<stringProp name="authbasic">${Basic}</stringProp>
<stringProp name="authpassword">ENC(dsxxxxxxxxxxxWiu+FCzl5+A==)</stringProp>
<stringProp name="authuser">${User}</stringProp>
<stringProp name="extratag"></stringProp>
x
x
y
y
z
z
```

When `TestPlan` is changed to `EvilPlan`, it works nicely, and the code is readable: the multi-line text is represented as-is.  If the
`@` character occurs, it has to be doubled up as `@@`, but it didn't occur.